# DragSortListView remove item after user confirm

Tags: android

The DragSortListView (https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview) is really good for drag sorting, I used it in my project, but I got a small problem.

I use the lib with remove mode, there is a delete-x action on right side of each list item, when user click the action, the item is removed, but I want to add a alert dialog for user to confirm the remove, but don't know how to do that.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override the remove function, like it says in the [Documentation](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview)

```
 @Override
 public void remove(int which) {
     Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
     builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.your_button_title, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             // do some custom delete code (e.g delete datamodel)
         }
     });

     builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter otherwise it will be gone!
        }
    });
    builder.setTitle(R.string.your_title);
    builder.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.your_message));
    builder.show();
 }
```

In order to get this method called you have to implement **RemoveListener** and of course you also have to add the listener:

```
myDragSortListView.setRemoveListener(this);
```

Hope that helps,!

Comment: @Olayinka, I have the same question, have you got it figured out?